# If I use :class_name attribute to has_one, what do I put in the migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, reference, has-one

I have a model in my Rails app that uses the `:class_name` attribute for `has_one`:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_one :main_bar, :class_name => "Bar"

  # ...
end
```

I'm a bit unsure what to put in the migration for this class now. Can I use references? What will Rails be looking for as the column name for `:main_bar`? Can I do it like this?

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.references :main_bar
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :foos
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't put anything in the table with the "has_one" relationship.  The foreign_key goes in the other table.  In your example above, you'd need to add a foreign key to your `bars` table.

In the migration you can use:

```
t.references :foo
```

or:

```
t.integer :foo_id
```

Either one will work.